# remove white spaces in a list of str

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a = ['bb', '', '', '', 'cc']
```

I want to remove '  ' in the list a and return the following list:

```
a = ['bb', 'cc']
```

so far, i have this code:

```
new_a = []
for item in a:
    if item != '':
    new_a.extend(item)
```

it gives me the same output:

```
new_a = ['b', 'b', 'c', 'c']
```

but i want:

```
new_a = ['bb', 'cc']
```

How can i modify my existing code to get   new_a = ['bb', 'cc'] without using any other modules?

Comment: Your code would have worked if you had ".append" instead of ".extend". Extend extends a list with another sequence, and it's interpreting 'bb' as being a sequence of two 'b' characters. Append treats "bb" as one value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a list-comp:

```
new_a = [el for el in a if el]
```

Take each element from `a` if it evaluates as "truthy"... If you wanted to do explicitly only include non-empty strings, then you'd use:

```
new_a = [el for el in a if el != '']
```

Alternatively, change your existing code to use `append` (which adds a new single element to the end of a list) instead of `extend` (which adds an iterable of items to the end - 'bb' is two items - hence you get `b` and `b` separately):

```
new_a = []
for item in a:
    if item != '':
        new_a.append(item)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option to solve your problem, `''` is a string object of length Zero, so you can use filter on list comprehension to get only the string with len > 0.

```
>>> a = ['bb', '', '', '', 'cc']
>>> filter(lambda x: len(x) > 0, a)
['bb', 'cc']
>>>
```

OR

```
>>> filter(lambda x: x.strip(), a)
['bb', 'cc']
>>>
```

Comment: That's a valid solution, but less elegant than list comprehensions as showed by Jon Clements.